# Does java serialization in some way change object?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, future, defaulttablemodel

I have defaultTableModel object stored inside a serializable ProductObj class.

```
public class ProductObj implements Serializable{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 79839857245324985L;

   private Integer taskID;
   private List<String> data;
   private JFreeChart climateChartPanel;
   private JFreeChart productivityChartPanel;
   private JFreeChart developmentChartPanel;
   private DefaultTableModel developmentTable;
   private DefaultTableModel productivityTable;
```

In all cases I can visualize developmentTable Jtable normally.
But for productivityTable, When I did not comment the commented line, I get a null exception when trying to visualize the jTable. In some way, serialization appears to interfere with the object.

This productivityTable is generated by 'n' threads, in those threads it is a volatile static object, but in the end it is stored in a future that is stored in a List.

```
private void serialize(String path) throws Exception {
    List<ProductObj> products = new ArrayList<>(controller.getFutures().size());
    for(Future<ProductObj> f : controller.getFutures())
        products.add(f.get());

    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Util.PathNameThisOS(path+"/"+"SimulationObjects.srz")); 
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut)) 
    {
        //out.writeObject(products);
    }

    products = unserialize(path);
}
```

here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:371)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:335)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthViewportUI.update(SynthViewportUI.java:168)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5230)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5178)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4989)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Serializing Swing components is generally considered to have been a bad idea. Decouple your data objects from your UI objects if you need to transmit or store the data.

Comment: Curious, why DefaultTableModel implements Serializable if it isn't a good idea?

Comment: @chrylis He has done exactly that. He isn't serializing a Swing object, he is serializing its (`Serializable`) model. That's exactly what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @user2884025 When it was designed, serialisation was used to transmit content over the wire, while this might still be possible, it's no longer consider a good idea to serialize the actual model, but the content instead.  The model carries additional information which might not be serializable, like listeners, so the state can become unstable.  Serialization of objects for their long term storage is also considered a bad idea and you should have a look at technologies like JAXB instead

Comment: @EJP But `ProductObj` contains Swing components as well as the `TableModel`s

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the information, I will rewrite the process so it construct the model after serialization/deserialization. I figured it could be not a good long term storage, so I stored results in textual form, that are possible to be processed, I'm only using serialization to access results without computing them again.

Comment: @EJP Is `JFreeChart` not a Swing component?

Comment: @chrylis both JFreeChart and Swing extends AWT Drawable, JFreeChart did not extends any Swing class but it extends EventListener... I believe that isn't a good idea to serialize it too.